# Do you use the default (package) visibility in Java?

Tags: java, visibility

Default visibility in java means only other classes in the same java package can access it. I certainly see the use of it, and have used it in several occasions.

On the other hand, 90% of the default visibility I encounter is simply from a developer that forgot to add any visibility keyword.

So, on the one hand, there's legitimate uses, on the other, it often masks bad code. What do you do in your development teams?

Comment: Code review must address such concerns :) Static analysis tools can come handy like PMD, check style if you want to apply stringent coding guidelines.

Comment: This question is to debate something, in SO we expect questions that can be answered, not debated

Comment: @AmitD valid point. In that case, I'd make a specific point of looking for all default access at the code revieweing stage.

Comment: @mael I was hoping people would provide hard facts one way or another.  I cast a first close vote myself, but don't delete the question just yet in case you agree (Oh god, I hope I haven't just started a debate on a debate)

Comment: Too bad there is no keyword to specify package visibility. It would allow to distinguish "package because I forgot or because I don't know what to put" and "package because I choose". Personally, when I choose to use package visibility, I end the declaration line with two `;` (`int x;;`)

Comment: @NicolasCenerario I fully agree. The double `;`, however, would set off other rules, and might be removed by auto code formaters. I use it so seldom, I often add something on the lines of `//Default access is intentional`

Comment: Default access is probably the most common access level I use, actually, quite deliberately.  I encounter lots of classes that have implementation details spread through several classes, and don't want to expose those details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I generally try to get everyone to start with the most limited scope and only start to expand outward if we see that it's necessary in the design. Occasionally the decision to move from `private` to `package-private` is also driven by our need to write tests without having to go down the route of using a mocking framework (see [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/)).

To add to this, we follow the same mentality on mutability. Everything starts out as `final` and only as we see the need to modify state do we remove it.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. I'd be all for it if there was a keyword for "package visibility", instead of a blank implying it.

Comment: A good approach. Interesting point about testing.

Comment: This is basically the same approach I've always used, and it drives me nuts when other developers don't follow suit.

Answer (score 5):

If I specifically want package access I put **/* package */** prior to the definition of the method/variable etc. to ensure people know I actually meant that, and wasn't being lazy. I rarely use it though.

Answer (score 4):

I encourage people to use `private` which I would have preferred to be the default.

Form time to time, I run a code analysis which reduces the access modifiers to only what is needed.

Comment: Agreed, I've used [UCDDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) precisely for that

Comment: I use IntelliJ which has a bulk quick fix facility. ;)

Comment: Bulk fix makes my spidey-code-quality sense tingle :) I'll check it out though

Comment: Like "unnecessary semicolon", is anyone going to fix that manually. But if you can do a whole project with one click, maybe.  IntelliJ have about 200 auto-fixed checks, and some are dangerous esp if you don't have the whole code base to hand.