# Best practices with class visibility

Tags: java

Is it best practice to have all the classes public in a Java project? I have noticed that in all Java projects I have worked with, there have only been public classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a guideline, no.

The information hiding principle tells us to only exposed what is *required*, and nothing more, to minimize coupling.

So, for example, if a class lets you handle logic in a separate class easier, and is only used by that class, there's no reason to have it public, nor should you make it public.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is "no!"

The slightly more complicated one is that you should only make a class public if it needs to be used by other classes outside it's own package.  But if, like me, you break you project up into many packages for readability, then then if will often be the case that your classes will need to be public to be usable.

While your question is simple to ask, it is far from simple in its nature.  Much will depend upon the kind of code your writing.  It you're writing a library then use externally is probably high on your agenda.  In an application less so.

I have found that I prefer the public approach.  I try and design for reuse because it keeps my options open, causes me to think more carefully about my implementation because of the reuse issues, and that leads to better code.  But it really is horses for courses, you are the biggest variable in this equation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, For top level class's, If you want other class's in a different package to view your class you should `mark it public`. If you only want class's in the same package to view you class `mark it default`(no-modifier).

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is really, should all top level classes be public? I think it boils down to the usage of the package access that you do in your project. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726651/do-you-use-the-default-package-visibility-in-java) was relevant to that, some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Usually most classes are indeed public but there are cases when you might want to use default or private scope as well.

A class using the default scope is only accessible to other classes in the same package. In case of helper classes for example it's often a good practice to limit their use this way as your code becomes more [encapsulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). The private scope can often be used for inner classes for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. There are lot of classes with other access specifiers or even anonymous. For an example, you can write private or anonymous classes that can be registered to listeners like 
'ActionListener' and 'ItemListener'. Just like that, for various purposes, we do write lot of classes with no public specifier. It really helps to separate your work into pieces.

However, in Java, normally every source file contains a public class. That is because if your source file's name is 'Reader.java', you cannot have a private or other access specifier  for the class 'Reader' inside that source file. It must be public or default. Apart from that, no other class can have the access specifier 'public' instead of 'Reader' class.

Other thing is, private, protected and other types (except default) of classes cannot be written in a source file as "Independent classes". For an example, following is an error

**Check.java**

```
private class Check
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is not best practice.  You are seeing it because most programmers don't know that a top-level class doesn't have to be public.

Ideally, a package isn't just a way to organize classes into groups.  There is no minimum or maximum number of classes that belong in a single package;  rather, subpackages should be created only when there is a need for package-level classes and/or members.  Java APIs do this a lot, and since the javadoc distributed from Sun/Oracle is generated for protected-level classes and members, some packages may appear to be sparse, even to the point of appearing nonsensically so.

For instance, the [javax.swing.colorchooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/colorchooser/package-summary.html) package appears to have only four classes, but it actually has 17 (actual number may vary depending on the version of Java).  Four are public;  the rest are only for use with JColorChooser internals.

I've found that an inner class that is becoming too big to be easily maintained as an inner class is usually a good candidate for being a non-public top-level class.